# Heroku Ruby error on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm going through the Getting Started guide step by step.  I am now on Declare App Dependencies.
(I am running locally on Windows 8.1)

When I run "bundle install", I have the following output:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.0
Using i18n 0.6.11

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS', 'Init_generator'"  > generator-i386-mingw32.def'
make: *** [generator-i386-mingw32.def] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

It looks to me like the error is in the line "C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku...".  The only parenthesis here is in (x86) - the standard 32-bit program files folder for Windows since XP.

I read somewhere that Ruby & Gems don't play well with folders that have spaces in the name.  It would seem that I have to move Heroku to a different folder than "Program Files (x86)"

Is that right?  Do I need to move my Heroku installation?
If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Windows and development , not a great love story

Comment: I would suggest removing it completely and installing **newer** Ruby (2.1+) in proper location (to path without spaces). And yes, running Rails in Linux is far easier, even combined with necessity to run it in a virtual machine. You're unlikely to deploy your Rails app on a Windows server anyway, and keeping working and running environments similar helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks for that advice.  It would be nicer, of course, if Heroku published this little tidbit before us noobs wasted a week trying to get it all working.   It's probably a good thing for me to attempt to get a Linux VM going ... it's been many years since I did that.

Comment: @CaffeineCoder: I'd rather say Windows support for <anything> not a great love story (Ruby, Python, whatever...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who come after, the answer is:
DON'T ATTEMPT TO RUN HEROKU ON A WINDOWS BOX.  Get yourself a Linux VM and get it going on that.